# Trouble trying to install MIT-Scheme on MacOSX Snow Leopard

Tags: scheme, installation, mit-scheme

I am trying to install MIT-Scheme so that i can use it off my terminal instead of using an IDE, however, I am having difficulty trying to find tutorials that are actually up to date and works.

Comment: You need to specify which implementation you're trying to install -- there are huge differences between them.

Comment: mit-scheme, but i found out using sudo port works, does it usually take really long during the build process?

Comment: I have no idea, but I edited your question for that.

Comment: or, i'm trying to use http://download.racket-lang.org/racket-5-1-bin-i386-osx-mac-dmg.html (racket) but instead of going through command prompt, this is a separate program. is there a way to directly install it so i can run it off my terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install MIT Scheme through Macports, and it will probably take a long time (it's compiling it from source, I think). You can also get a precompiled binary from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/) which will install an MIT-Scheme.app which starts Edwin an Emacs port or something which includes a Scheme debugger and REPL. But you can also start it from the command line.

Check to see where it installed to, on my machine it's here `/Applications/mit-scheme.app/Contents/Resources/` but that might vary. Add this directory to your `PATH` by editing `~/.bash_profile` and adding this:

```
export PATH=$PATH":/Applications/mit-scheme.app/Contents/Resources/"
```

Check with `which mit-scheme` to make sure it installed correctly.

As for Racket, there's also a precompiled binary available from [here](http://racket-lang.org/download/). (It might be in Macports but it might not be, or in Fink, I don't know. I try to avoid those and use Homebrew if possible.) This is a `dmg` file which you can extract and put wherever you want. I put mine in `~/bin` and added `~/bin/racket/bin/` to my `PATH` as well, same process as above, but you can put it anywhere, `/Applications/` or whatever.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a odd answer since it's about Racket for a question that was originally about MIT Scheme, but since you tried Racket too...

To run Racket from the terminal, you need to use the `racket` executable, which is found in the `bin` subdirectory.  For example, if you install it at `/Applications/Racket-5.1`, then you'd run `/Applications/Racket-5.1/bin/racket`.  (And you could modify your `$PATH` or add some symlink to make it possible to run without specifying the full path.)

Comment: Where do I go to edit my $PATH so I can make this an executable? Sorry i'm really new to this.

Comment: I've added the path, but it's still says: -bash: racket: command not found

Comment: Sadly, there are about 50 things that could be going on here.  Before doing any of the other 49, check to see whether 'racket' is in your path by running 'which racket'.

Comment: which racket returns nothing, so i assume nothing is installed.

Comment: IIRC there was some OSX thing where you specify your PATH, but it was obscure.  Probably easiest to do in your shell startup scripts (which depends on the shell, and hopefully they're over using tcsh as the default).  A symlink might be overall easier.

Comment: @diesel : no, don't assume that nothing is installed. Instead, assume that you haven't yet successfully added 'racket' to your path. Eli's right about the crazy Mac thing, but you can ignore that, because if you're talking about running it from the command line, it'll use the standard shell startup scripts. The first question: did you download and unpack the Racket package? The second question: *where* did you unpack it? One place to look would be in your Downloads directory.

Comment: i've added this correctly now. how can i enable it so that.. i can do something like.. mzscheme filename testfile ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the detailed answer [here](https://jacksonisaac.wordpress.com/2014/03/25/installing-scheme-on-mac-os-x/).

Here is a short version:

1. Download .dmg file of MIT-Scheme. 32-bit or 64-bit based on your hardware architecture.
2. After installation run the following commands

For 32-bit package:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MIT\:GNU\ Scheme.app/Contents/Resources /usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-i386

sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-i386/mit-scheme /usr/bin/scheme
```

For 64-bit package:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MIT\:GNU\ Scheme.app/Contents/Resources /usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-x86-64

sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-x86-64/mit-scheme /usr/bin/scheme
```

3. To run MIT-Scheme from your terminal just type 'scheme' in the command prompt.